# UILabel text doesn't update after receiving notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When I set a label using this

```
self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method, it works when the view gets loaded but I also want to set the label when a notification was received.

```
- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
  if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"versionNotification"]){
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the notification!");
    self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
  }
}
```

The string `"Successfully received the notification!"` gets printed out, but the label doesn't get updated/set with the string unless I reload the view again and the `viewDidLoad` method gets called.

**EDIT**

I found out that it has nothing to do with the notification, when I put `self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];` in another function is doesn't get set aswell... it only gets set when I put it in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Is it possible that the notification is being received before the `UILabel` is added to the view hierarchy or even before the view is loaded at all?

Comment: This is correct. What is you question?

Comment: Check your versionLbl is valid UILabel or nil.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"]; });

Comment: what is the value of [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"]?       NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"]);

Comment: The label is on my storyboard and the label is not nil and the valeu of the UserDefaults is 0.6

Comment: Check before posting notification, you are setting value in nsuserdefaults or not?

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"] will not change I think

Comment: The label is empty, when the notification is called, then it needs to add the UserDefault to the label, if I print out the UserDefault is shows me the correct string but it doesn't get set on the label for some reason

Comment: @nonuma i think you use separate Thread not able to update UI so use my code lines and try. as you describe this can be 1 reason

Comment: I've tried your solution, but this doesn't work

Comment: @Dilip If notification name were the problem the log message wouldn't be printed either

Comment: Did you synchronise it ?

Comment: yes I have, check my edited question

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your label is not `nil` and that you're calling UIKit methods in the main thread. You can try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that, it has actually nothing to do with the notification, when I put it in another function it doesn't work either, it only works when I put the self.versionLbl.text in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Try printing if self.versionLbl is nil. It might be that the is no longer pointing to your label.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the object stored in `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];` is actually a `NSString` object.

If not you have several alternatives:

```
self.versionLbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"version"];
```

or

```
id versionObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
self.versionLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", versionObject];
```

or

```
id versionObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
self.versionLbl.text = [versionObject stringValue];
```

Comment: Its a NSString that is saved in the UserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

Check IBOutlet at your UILabel. You should connect IBOutlet UILabel declared with a Property with label on your .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

If its loading after the view has already loaded, try [myLabel setNeedsDisplay];